# redirect to vf page after site login

Tags: force.com-sites

After logging in to site its again redirecting to login page.
SiteLoginController code is as below

```
global with sharing class SiteLoginController {
    global String username {get; set;}
    global String password {get; set;}

    global PageReference login() {
        String startUrl = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('startURL');
        return Site.login(username, password, 'http://rp-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/sfdcprepare/QuizPage');
    }

    global SiteLoginController () {}
}
```

can anybody pls help me in this regard?

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when your landing page is not available in the portal. Make sure the `QuizPage` is available for portal and it should work.

[Update]

I see that you are not even using the startURL parameter when doing Site.login so I'm simply sharing my working code which you can modify and use. Also, you are not doing `portalPage.setRedirect(true);`

I hope this helps.

```
global with sharing class SiteLoginController {

  //set username/ password variables via page
    global String username {get; set;}
    global String password {get; set;}

    global PageReference login() {

      //static org-id and portal id
      String strOrgID = '';
      String strPortalID = '';
      String strURL = '';
      //start url of the page
      String startUrl = strUrl + '/secur/login_portal.jsp?orgId=' + strOrgID + '&portalId=' + strPortalID;

    startUrl += '&un=' + username;
        startUrl += '&pw='+ password;

        //set reference and attempt login
        PageReference portalPage = new PageReference(startUrl);
        portalPage.setRedirect(true);
        PageReference p = Site.login(username, password, startUrl);

        //if p==null, no login
        if (p == null) {
              return Site.login(username, password, null);
        } else {
              return portalPage;
        }
    }

    //test data provided by salesforce
     global SiteLoginController () {}

    @IsTest(SeeAllData=true) global static void testSiteLoginController () {
        // Instantiate a new controller with all parameters in the page
        SiteLoginController controller = new SiteLoginController ();
        controller.username = 'test@salesforce.com';
        controller.password = '123456';

        System.assertEquals(controller.login(),null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I have added QuizPage to site.

Comment: If I try to load this URL - http://rp-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/sfdcprepare/QuizPage it returns URL does not exist. Are you sure this is a valid URL?

Comment: https://rohitp-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/sfdcprepare/QuizPage   is the URL

Comment: The above code snippet mentions - return Site.login(username, password, 'http://rp-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/sfdcprepare/QuizPage'); Do you have the correct URL in there?

Comment: yeah its correct.                                                                                                                                     
    global PageReference login() {
        String startUrl = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('startURL');
        return Site.login(username, password, 'https://rohitp-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/sfdcprepare/QuizPage');    
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use this..

```
return Site.login(username, password, 'https://rp-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/sfdcprepare/QuizPage');
```

You can do one more thing is that make secure site using the checkbox on site setting "**Require Secure Connections (HTTPS)**".

Comment: I tried by this way as well, but its not working